# Question concerning limit superior and inferior.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ be two real sequences such that $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n$. Is it true that $\lim \sup a_n \leq \lim\inf b_n $? Outline the proof if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=(-1)^n+\frac 12$ (such that $a_n< b_n$ for all $n$). Now $$1=\lim\sup a_n\not\leq\lim\inf b_n=-\tfrac 12$$ Thus, your conjecture is false.

Comment: I believe $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}$ is nice.

Comment: @sinbadh, I don't quite understand your comment. Perhaps you could clearify?

Comment: what if we replace less than equal to by strictly less than sign?

Comment: @LavKumar, your conjecture is still false. I edited the answer to fit $a_n<b_n$. Your conjecture *is* true if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are converging. Actually, only one of both converging is perhaps enough

Comment: Before edited your answer, it looks like $a_n=b_n$.

Comment: @sinbadh, well, if $a_n=b_n$, then also $a_n\leq b_n$, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. And due to your original selection of $a_n$ and $b_n$, trivially $\underline{\lim}<\overline{\lim}$. Indeed, it is trivial for all divergent sequences. Therefore, i suppose you only had a typo error

Answer (score 0):

Two general observations to supplement the simple and explicit example that @vrugtehagel gave:

**1.** Let $\{a_n\}$ be any sequence such that $\liminf a_n = -\infty$ and $\limsup a_n = +\infty.$ Then for each fixed positive real number $r,$ the sequence defined by $b_n = a_n + r$ has the property that $a_n < b_n$ for each $n$ and $\limsup a_n = +\infty$ and $\liminf b_n = -\infty.$ Thus, "$\limsup a_n \leq \liminf b_n$" can fail in a strong way.

**2.** Let $\{a_n\}$ be any sequence such that $-\infty < \liminf a_n < \limsup a_n < +\infty.$ Then we can easily modify $\{a_n\}$ to obtain a sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that $a_n < b_n$ for each $n$ and $\limsup a_n > \liminf b_n.$ Simply let $b_n = a_n - \frac{1}{2}(\limsup a_n - \liminf a_n).$